# SQL Email (.com) Reference

Tags: mysql

My school work has asked me to retrieve information from all customers with emails ending in ".com" I cannot find any information anywhere. Can you help me out? Below is what I have tried as well as many other variations.

```
SELECT first_name AND last_name FROM customerform WHERE email LIKE('.com')
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work either. Thanks for trying though. I had already tried that code.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how `LIKE` works, nor how `SELECT` works. Instead:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customerform WHERE email LIKE '%.com'
```

Here `%` means "begins with" or "blah blah blah" in more casual parlance.

Remember things like [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) are fully documented and there's no shame in checking how they work before running your statement. We all need to check that we're doing it correctly.

Comment: Great answer, just to add, `%` may also be referred to as a "wildcard".

Comment: @JeremyHarris It goes by many names, and that's a good one to keep in mind, especially in this case. Good point.

Comment: Thanks but that did not work either. Thanks for trying though. I had already tried that code.

Comment: I think the period is a pattern matching character, which means it needs to be escaped. Try this: `SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customerform WHERE email LIKE '%.com' ESCAPE '.';`

Comment: @JeremyHarris I don't think `.` is significant to [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). `%` and `_` are. If this doesn't match it's possible there's trailing spaces in the fields that should otherwise match. Check with `SELECT HEX(email) FROM customers` and if you don't see entries ending in `...6C2E636F6D` but instead `2020202020` then you have trailing spaces and you need to trim and fix your email addresses. Make sure you're using `VARCHAR` and not `CHAR` for some reason.

Comment: No luck yet but thanks. Also the comment above stating I don't know how to use the SELECT or LIKE, I am just curious what exactly you did so differently? Your syntax is identical without the AND which i didn't mean to have in the statement. Also if you are going to post answers possibly check them before posting otherwise its just wasting peoples time checking out false codes. Thanks again.